# How to use QMediaMetaData correctly to define media files parameters?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to determine the parameters of the audio file: bitrate, sampling rate, bit depth, audio format.

I have tried to use it like that:

```
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaMetaData>
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaObject>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
.
.
.
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_1_clicked()
{
   QMediaObject mediafile;
   QString file_name = "/run/media/helg/WDC/test.aac";   
   mediafile.setMedia(QUrl(file_name));
   QString bitrate = mediafile.metaData(QMediaMetaData::AudioBitRate).toString();
   .
   .
   .
}
.
.
.
```

But it doesn't work:

> error: no matching constructor for initialization of `QMediaObject`.

I'm not even sure if I should use a `QMediaObject` or something else.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it compile? Does it run? Does it crash? ...?
Please add more details to your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'QMediaObject'. 

I'm just not even sure if I should use a QMediaObject or something else.

Comment: Edit your question to add at the bottom an explanation of what you want to achieve. We can't help you out without knowing what your goal is.
Adding the error message from your comment to the original question would also be a wise thing to do :)

Comment: I need to determine the parameters of the audio file: bitrate, sampling rate, bit depth, audio format.

Comment: According to the [QT documentation](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/texmaker_v5.0.2/qt57/doc/qtmultimedia/qmediaobject.html), you need to pass parent and service objects in the QMediaObject constructor with this signature:  `QMediaObject::QMediaObject(QObject *parent, QMediaService *service)`

Comment: I'm just not sure if I should use a QMediaObject here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're welcome.

---

1. Define a player variable:

```
private:
    QMediaPlayer *m_player;
```

In your code:

```
   m_player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
  connect(m_player, SIGNAL(mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)), this, SLOT(onMediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)));

   m_player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:\\yourMediaFileAddress"));
```

3. Define the `onMediaStatusChanged` slot e.g. as follows:

```
void MainWindow::onMediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus status)
{
    if (status == QMediaPlayer::LoadedMedia)
        GetMetaData(m_player);
}
```

The `GetMetaData()` method lists all available metadata:

```
void MainWindow::GetMetaData(QMediaPlayer *player)
{
   // Get the list of keys there is metadata available for
   QStringList metadatalist = player->availableMetaData();

   // Get the size of the list
   int list_size = metadatalist.size();

   //qDebug() << player->isMetaDataAvailable() << list_size;

   // Define variables to store metadata key and value
   QString metadata_key;
   QVariant var_data;

   for (int indx = 0; indx < list_size; indx++)
   {
     // Get the key from the list
     metadata_key = metadatalist.at(indx);

     // Get the value for the key
     var_data = player->metaData(metadata_key);

    qDebug() << metadata_key << var_data.toString();
   }
 }
```

The output on a sample media file is something like this:

```
"AudioBitRate" "128000"
"AudioCodec" "MPEG Audio Layer-3 (MP3)"
"ChannelCount" "2"
"Copyright" "SaM"
"Duration" "5069876"
"PixelAspectRatio" ""
"Resolution" ""
"SampleRate" "48000"
"VideoBitRate" "1028056"
"VideoCodec" "MPEG-4 part 2 Video (MP4V)"
"VideoFrameRate" "24"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The `QMediaMetaData` just provides media information and therefore it cannot be instantiated by developer. You can use this method:

```
QFile sourceFile;   // class member.
QAudioOutput* audio; // class member.
{
    sourceFile.setFileName("/tmp/test.raw");
    sourceFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    QAudioFormat format;
    // Set up the format, eg.
    format.setSampleRate(8000);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleSize(8);
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

    QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
    if (!info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
        qWarning() << "Raw audio format not supported by backend, cannot play audio.";
        return;
    }

    audio = new QAudioOutput(format, this);
    connect(audio, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), this, SLOT(handleStateChanged(QAudio::State)));
    audio->start(&sourceFile);
}
```

Reference: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiooutput.html

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I need. I don't need to set parameters bitrate, sampling rate, bit depth, audio format  and play the file. I need to get this parameters from an existing file for subsequent transcoding of the audio file to another format, I have audio converter (https://github.com/SimplestStudio/simplest-studio).